# Java: "for" change condition?

Tags: java

```
while(result.length() != allText){
    b = (boolean)(i < variable);
    for(i = firstR; b; i++){
       //do something
}
    b = (i < variable);
}
```

Am i can change for condition by boolean? 
In my code *b = condition is converted true or false*. I want to keep it by *condition*.

Comment: Do you have something against `for(i = firstR; i<variable; i++){`? Because otherwise, you would have to have `b = (boolean)(i < variable);` **inside** the `for` loop somewhere. But it's a strange way of using the loop ...

Comment: well i thinked can i change "i < variable"

Comment: by changeable variable

Comment: It's not clear what you want. If you want some externally modifiable condition, you should implement it as such. For example, as a `Predicate`.

Comment: `b` holds the **value** calculated at the time of assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
b = (boolean)(i < variable);
```

does not mean that the value of `b` "binds" to the condition `i < variable`. i.e. it does not mean that when `i` is changed to a value larger than `variable`, `b`'s value will also change. `b` is only assigned once.

You either put `i < variable` in the loop condition, or you can use a lambda (predicate):

```
// assuming i is int
IntPredicate b = x -> x < variable;

// change the loop
for(i = firstR; b.test(i) ; i++){
```

If you don't know what lambdas are, they basically represent anonymous classes. The lambda expression in the above code represents this anonymous class:

```
new IntPredicate() {
    public boolean test(int x) {
        return x < variable;
    }
}
```

IMO, you should not use a predicate. Just write the condition properly where it should be. It is way easier to understand a for loop in this form:

```
for (i = x ; i < y ; i++)
```

than in this form:

```
for (i = x ; b ; i++)
```

Comment: with this can i bind condition

Comment: There's actually an `IntPredicate`. And your loop will not compile, since Java does not support using b as if it was a method. `b.test(i)` is mandatory.

Comment: @GreedRuler With the lambda, yes, the value of `b(i)` can change if `i` is changed.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Oops! I used Swift too much... Fixed

Comment: what 's  lambda?

Comment: @GreedRuler In my answer, `x -> x < variable` is a lambda expression. Read this for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html
They can represent anonymous classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a boolean conditional then you should change

for(i = firstR; b; i++)

to

while(b) //Do something

or while(i < variable)